# Set background color of current row in vb.net (aspx) loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops

I am trying to loop through all rows on my GridView1 and change the backgournd colour of the rows as they are processed.

The loop works perfectly, but for some reason the line of code to set the Back Color is not being honoured.

```
nextRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue
```

Here is the complete loop.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim counter As Integer = GridView1.SelectedIndex + 1
    Dim nextRow As GridViewRow

    nextRow = GridView1.Rows(0)
    If counter = GridView1.Rows.Count Then
        nextRow = GridView1.Rows(0)

    Else

        'formatting
        nextRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue

        nextRow = GridView1.Rows(counter)
        CompileHTML(GridView1.Rows(i))
        ExportHTML(GridView1.Rows(i))

    End If
Next
```

Comment: You are setting backcolor before nextRow = GridView1.Rows(counter). I think, you must move nextRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue row after setting nextRow

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting the value of nextRow to the first row directly above the if statement so nextRow is always GridView1.Rows(0) when backcolor is set.

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue
Next
```